# Import Vlc module in python

Tags: python, vlc

I am trying to create a media player using vlc and python but it throws an Error which is No module named vlc. how to fix this?

Comment: download [vlc.py](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=generated;b=HEAD) and put it in the same folder than your project.

Comment: @rsm - or into the `site-packages` for making it available for every python project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a same issue. You should try `sudo pip install python-vlc`

Answer (score 20):

Install

```
$ sudo pip install python-vlc
```

Then you can import the python module

```
import vlc
```

Comment: Is `sudo` required? I've already got it installed and I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

There is also python-vlc

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-vlc/1.1.2

Download the .tar.gz file into your project and unzip it. Once unzipped, run:

```
python setup.py install
```

This will install the python-vlc module for you and then try importing it in your python script.

P.S Make sure you are inside the unzipped folder and you can see the setup.py file.

Comment: there is no option to extract that file

Answer (score 0):

I had same (windows, Jupyter, Python 3). Think downloading the .exe file was the thing that fixed it

https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.11/win64/vlc-3.0.11-win64.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30519331)

Answer (score 0):

Install it using `pip`:

```
pip install python-vlc==3.0.6109
```

Then import it in your Python file:

```py
import vlc
```