# not able to play youtube media using vlc in python

Tags: python, vlc, pafy

I'm trying to play a random youtube video using pafy and vlc. But when I'm executing the script :

```
        import vlc 
        import cv2            

        url = "Youtube_URL"            
        video = pafy.new(url)
        best = video.getbest()
        playurl = best.url
        ins = vlc.Instance()
        player = ins.media_player_new()
        Media = ins.media_new(playurl)
        Media.get_mrl()
        player.set_media(Media)
        player.play()
```

I'm getting below error :

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Instance'

I've tried a lot but **vlc.Instance()** is not working, I don't know why. I will appreciate any help/inputs.

Comment: "Instance = vlc.Instance()" won't work as you have to assign a variable and not a class name to a new object. Try to "instance = vlc.Instance()" instead.

Comment: my bad :( I have modified the code, still the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vlc.Instance: AttributeError("module 'vlc' has no attribute 'Instance'")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405364/vlc-instance-attributeerrormodule-vlc-has-no-attribute-instance)

Comment: Does this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405364/vlc-instance-attributeerrormodule-vlc-has-no-attribute-instance) help you out?

Comment: @Hagbard: I have already checked these answers, none are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know if you have solved the problem already. I don't really know why this happens. I only figured out that it happens when you execute pip3 install python-vlc(or something like that).

I think they might have changed some methods and objects in more recent versions.However this works for me.
Here is the oficial link where I downloaded it from:

https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/1.1.2/#files

Get the tar.gz file, extract the content and change directory, then run: 
sudo python3 install setup.py

You have to uninstall first the module that you installed previously:
 python3 uninstall vlc and python3 uninstall python-vlc. Install the one that you downloaded and then it might ask you to install again module vlc(not python-vlc). Hope this helps!